# Defining Continuous Deployment

Tags: continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Questions we get a lot:

- What is Continuous Deploymenyt?
- What do we deploy 'continuously'?
- How does it differ from Continuous Delivery? Is there a difference?

My attempt at answering these questions on my blog post: [What is Continuous Deployment](http://sdarchitect.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/understanding-devops-part-6-continuous-deployment/)?

What is the generally accepted definition and distinction between Continuous Delivery and Continuous Deployment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general software development area and better fits programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Continuous delivery is a series of practices designed to ensure that code can be rapidly and safely deployed to production by delivering every change to a production-like environment and ensuring business applications and services function as expected through rigorous automated testing. Since every change is delivered to a staging environment using complete automation, you can have confidence the application can be deployed to production with a push of a button when the business is ready.

Continuous deployment is the next step of continuous delivery: Every change that passes the automated tests is deployed to production automatically. Continuous deployment should be the goal of most companies that are not constrained by regulatory or other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Continuous deployment is one of the steps of a continuous delivery system. There is a very enlightening blog written by Martin Fowler from thoughtworks on Continuous *(Integration,Delivery , testing) etc. I would suggest you read through it to understand it.

There are a lot of facets to the entire Continuous * Ecosystem( Build,integration,testing,deploy,UAT, delivery,) that cannot be covered in a single comment/answer thread. It surely deserves its own space on a blog/wiki/bliki. You should probably read a few  blogs and search for understanding there.